# Is the set $\left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n = 2,3,4,\ldots\right\}$ a countable infinite set?

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to answer a homework question and I need to know if the set $E = \left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n = 2,3,4,\ldots\right\}$ is countable or not.  So $E=\left\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4},\ldots\right\}$.

I think it is a countable infinite set because we have a bijection from the set $E$ to the natural numbers correct? So $E$ and $N$ have the same orders and so $E$ is countable.

Is this right?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the obvious bijection with the naturals makes it countable.

Comment: You beat me; nice!

Comment: My answer was shorter. :)

Comment: Haha, true. =P By the way, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow E$ defined by $f(n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, due to the bijection with $\mathbb{N}$. In general, if there a bijection between two sets and one is countably infinite, so is the other, because you can also match one element in one set with exactly one of the other.